# How to decrease latency on Binance API orderbook calls?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, network-programming, bitcoin, ethereum

I am currently attempting to decrease latency when calling the orderbook with the Binance API.

I am getting a ping of ~7ms but the orderbook call takes ~200ms to download. I am using a VM hosted in the same AWS farm that Binance uses, and I am running on a network speed of ~800mbps. I do not understand why the orderbook call takes nearly two orders of magnitude more time to receive than the time it takes to ping the server when the size of the orderbook is relatively small.

Any help or insight into either the network, or restrictions imposed by Binance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two suggestions: One, don't ask for more information than you absolutely need. Two, measure to see what's taking the time -- is it mostly time to open the connection, time to send the query, time to first byte of reply, time to receive the reply, time to realize you have the entire reply, or what?

Comment: I agree with @DavidSchwartz. You need to profile you code and network traffic. As far as network traffic profiling, you can use `tcpfump` on the interface being used. You can then open the capture file in Wireshark to see if there are any red flags.

Comment: how do you know which AWS farm Binance uses? Also how much of an effect does the internet speed have since you are transmitting such small amounts of data?

Answer (score 5):

Important distinction:

- **Ping:** goes to the nearest CDN edge node, which responds to you; you don't get anywhere near a Binance server.
- **API request:** goes to the nearest CDN edge node, gets routed to the Binance server, gets processed, then the response is routed back to you.

Binance servers are hosted on AWS in Tokyo. If you place your host there, the latency will be about 12-15ms (2ms from when Binance sent the response.)

To lower the average latency, you may try to post idempotent requests in parallel, and then use the response that arrives first. It's rude but it gets the job done.

As a random note, client order IDs are reusable, which makes them useless as a method of making orders idempotent. (However, if you use fixed order sizes, you could preemptively lock all the rest of your funds, then hammer Binance with order placements knowing a duplicate order couldn't succeed since you wouldn't have funds.)

Comment: "try to post idempotent requests in parallel,"> POST is not an idempotent method,

Comment: @SmartManoj POST != post; let's say you have $100 and you post 5 request to buy something for $60: it's equivalent to posting just 1 of those requests since only the first one to arrive will succeed -- even if you used the POST HTTP method

Comment: How will you make truly parallel requests?

Comment: @SmartManoj I don't need to and that isn't the point. The point is that if I send multiple requests that would do the same (as long as only one of them can successfully complete), I can get a quicker execution on average: I get the speed of whichever gets there first.

Answer (score 0):

By now there are multiple api endpoint api/api1/api2/api3.binance.com
I pinged the endpoint using cmd. And the given method provided by @Tiana.
For me api2 had somehow the best latency. But not really better than api1 or api3.
Just the normla api had very bad latencies from time to time.
Apparently the endpoints are on different server i guess and the api. endpoint is overused a bit.
So i would suggest using the api2.binance.com endpoint